# Is SQL Injection possible in the below query

Tags: java, sql, oracle, code-injection

So I'm reviewing some code and Fortify marked the following query as SQL Injectible

```
"select"+seqName+".NEXTVAL from DUAL;"
```

Comment: It would be easier to tell if you gave some more code so we could see where seqName is coming from.

Comment: `seqName = " * from DUAL; --"` is a sql injection. So it is possible in your code

Comment: If `seqName` comes from some external source, then SQL injection is possible.

Comment: Use [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)s instead…

Comment: @deHaar PreparedStatements don't help with gluing in column names.

Comment: @khelwood Yes, just realized myself... I just never needed to glue in column names and didn't know it is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, absolutely. It is basically the archetypical example for SQL Injection vulnerability.

If `seqName` is something like `" * from User_passwords; --"` the select will query whatever table is used in `seqName`.

Of course this might not apply if `seqName` is from a secure source, like some hardcoded list inside the program for example.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the SQL injection, you'd need to assert the value of the string before concatenating it into the statement, which you can do using one of the `dbms_assert` subprograms, e.g. `DBMS_ASSERT.SQL_OBJECT_NAME`